# How can I modify created between scope with lambda written in Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While migrating my application from Rails 3.2 to Rails 4.2, I have seen many changes, in that, scope syntax is one of the thing.
I modified all the other scopes but worried of this one:

```
  scope :created_between, lambda { |start_at, end_at|
    { :conditions => {'users.created_at' => (start_at..end_at)} }
  }
```

The above scope gives the users created between particular days and the related controller method code is:

```
def user_count
    result = []
    [
      {:label => 'today', :start => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, :end => Time.zone.now.end_of_day},
      {:label => 'yesterday', :start => 1.days.ago.beginning_of_day, :end => 1.days.ago.end_of_day},
      {:label => 'this week', :start => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week, :end => Time.zone.now.end_of_week},
      {:label => 'last week', :start => 7.days.ago(Time.zone.now.beginning_of_week), :end => 7.days.ago(Time.zone.now.end_of_week)},
      {:label => 'this month', :start => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_month, :end => Time.zone.now.end_of_month},
      {:label => 'last month', :start => Time.zone.now.prev_month.beginning_of_month, :end => Time.zone.now.prev_month.end_of_month},
    ].each do |time_frame|
      result << [time_frame[:label], User.includes(:account).only_deleted.deleted_between(time_frame[:start], time_frame[:end]).count, User.includes(:account).with_deleted.created_between(time_frame[:start], time_frame[:end]).count]
    end
end
```

How to modify the above scope that matches the controller method with current Rails 4.2 syntax?

Comment: As it is you're issuing 12 round trips to the database with this code (once for deleted and once for not-deleted in each iteration of the loop). This could be accomplished with two queries, once for deleted and once for not-deleted, grouped by date. Then you could do the summation for each time frame in Ruby. See the documentation for [group](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group) and [count](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count).

Answer (score 0):

Rails 4.2 uses the shorter lambda style for scopes, so that will become something like:

```
scope :created_between, -> (start_at, end_at) { 
  where("? BETWEEN start_at AND end_at", 'users.created_at') 
}
```

Comment: You can use the "stabby lambda" version on any ruby version that supports it (1.9 and above) - rails doesn't care about that. The important change is using `where` rather than just a hash of query options